# Is it possible to use Math widget on Group widget?

Tags: tablesorter

On this example of TableSorter http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html you can have a subfooter with partial math funtions under each column.

I am trying to get that same info but on the Group widget from this example http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html.

On the Group example, when you order by "Numeric" you get some math info but only for the grouped cell like:

```
10 - 19  (3); subtotal:32
```

This is being acheived by this code:

```
  group_callback    : function($cell, $rows, column, table){
    // callback allowing modification of the group header labels
    // $cell = current table cell (containing group header cells ".group-name" & ".group-count"
    // $rows = all of the table rows for the current group; table = current table (DOM)
    // column = current column being sorted/grouped
    if (column === 2) {
      var subtotal = 0;
      $rows.each(function(){
        subtotal += parseFloat( $(this).find("td").eq(column).text() );
      });
      $cell.find(".group-count").append("; subtotal: " + subtotal );
    }
  },
```

I would like to have the same info on the group by column where i could define which function is being used in every column.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same info on the group by column"? The group callback includes a column index, isn't that what you need?

Comment: For example, on the Math example you have "Middle Total  $ 17,003.00  $ 14,886.00  $ 15,295.00  $ 47,184.00". I would like to have on the group something like this: "Middle (4)   $ 17,003.00  $ 14,886.00  $ 15,295.00  $ 47,184.00)" instead of "Middle (4)"

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that the math widget expects the values to be above the designated row (e.g. "above-sum") whereas the grouping widget adds rows above the group; also the math & group widgets have the same priority - the math widget would need to be called after the group widget, but when the math widget completes its calculation, it triggers an update which removes the group rows. You might be stuck using the grouping widget's complete callback to do all the calculations.